# attributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'end'

Tags: python

iam doing web scraping for weather forecast.

Code which I ran for this programing was

```
import re
import urllib.request
# https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Bangalore/forecasts/latest

city = input("Enter your city:")
url = 'https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/' + city + '/forecasts/latest'

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

data1 = data.decode('utf-8')


m = re.search('span class= "phrase"', data1)

start = m.end()

end = start + 100

newString = data1[start:end]

print(newString)
```

I get the following error

> ====================== RESTART: C:/Python/weather.py =======================
> Enter your city:Seattle
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Python/weather.py", line 15, in 
> start = m.end(print)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'end'

Comment: `m = re.search('span class= "phrase"', data1)` this returns None, you should use the beautifulsoup or other libraries for parsing web page content, regex is not good fit for this things.

Comment: 1. Check if data and data1 is of 'list' data type. Print them simply.
2. Print the 'start' and 'end' variables and verify they contain valid values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to traverse/search through a markup document like HTML.  It's designed to save you the trouble of parsing HTML with regex.

Like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Bangalore/forecasts/latest"

data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

soup.find("span", {"class": "phrase"}).text
#'Light rain (total 2mm), mostly falling on Sun night. Warm (max 30°C on Sat afternoon, min 20°C on Sat night). Wind will be generally light.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it on Jupyter Online. This line is giving you problem:

- m = re.search('span class= "phrase"', data1)

If you print the raw html you will notice that the syntax is:

- span class="phrase"

That is, you are adding an extra space next to the '=' symbol to the regular expression making it return None.

[Jupyter Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuZhg.png)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know space error in my code., Now I am able to run the program.